# Python - Problema com df.apply(function)

Tags: python, query, pandas

beleza?

tem como me darem uma ajudinha? se liga só.

Eu tenho um dataframe com algumas informações de string e queria mudar elas para texto.

Para simplificar, imagina que a tabela contenha informações do sexo da pessoa, por exemplo, homem ou mulher. Meu programa classificaria como 0 ou 1.

Até que ele consegue fazer isso bem. Mas o problema é quando tenho muita informação dentro da tabela, o programa fica o dia todo rodando. quando fico sem paciência e cancelo, as vezes ele converteu as unidades e outras vezes não.

o meu código python ta assim oh:

````
```python
y='Indice da Tabela'

def toText(x):
        return(list(train[y].value_counts().index).index(x))

train[y]=train[y].apply(toText)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o problema. Provavelmente a função de ficar indexando os índices o tempo todo na variável estava dando problemas. joguei a parte de `(train[i].value_counts().index)` para fora do loop e dei uma melhoradinha no código.

````
```python
def transf(df):
    nome=list(df)
    for i in (nome):
        def toText(x):
            return(y_.index(x))
        y_ = list(train[i].value_counts().index)
        if df[i].dtype == 'O':
            train[i]=train[i].apply(toText)
````

Ficou até que o código ficou atraente no final.